# MS Developer Subscription integration with Teams Assignments

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm interested in developing solutions for use in schools, integrating with Microsoft Teams for Education.
I have joined the MS Developer Programme and am up and running with my Developer E5 Subscription, but it seems that the options for creating Classes are not present and are specific to an Education licence.

Am I missing something here? How do other developers configure a Teams environment that behaves like a school and develop/test with Class Assignment data?

I have now made some limited progress. In the absence of a UI capability to add classes, I've managed to use the Graph Explorer to create a team with the classroom template as follows:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')",
  "displayName": "My Class Team",
  "description": "My Class Team’s Description"
}
```

This team then allows me to add a class notebook and add Teachers and Students, but still no assignments.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating assignment in side Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-assignment-in-microsoft-teams-23c128d0-ec34-4691-9511-661fba8599be) is available in Education licence currently. You could build your own app and integrate it with Teams. Here is a detail [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/building-an-app).